# how to use flashcards package and print one per page?

Tags: geometry, flashcards

I'm using the [flashcards package](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/flashcards/flashcards.pdf) to create a deck of cards.  For home printing, I usually use the avery paper which works great (printed 10 to a page).  I also want to print them professionally and need to create a PDF with one card per page, but I don't know how to configure the paper so that it works.  I've got it almost working, except the cards show up portrait instead of landscape.

Here's a simplified example that illustrates the problem:

```
\documentclass[cards, backs]{flashcards}
\geometry{landscape, paperwidth=3.25in,paperheight=2in,margin=0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{flashcard}{}
   Guten morgen.
\end{flashcard}

\begin{flashcard}{}
   Guten abend.
\end{flashcard}

\end{document}
```

In the same directory, I created a "cards.cfg" file to specific the paper format:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1996/12/01]
\ProvidesFile{cards.cfg}
\newcommand{\cardpapermode}{landscape}
\newcommand{\cardpaper}{letterpaper}
\newcommand{\cardrows}{1}
\newcommand{\cardcolumns}{1}
\setlength{\cardheight}{2.0in}
\setlength{\cardwidth}{3.5in}
\setlength{\topoffset}{0.0in}
\setlength{\oddoffset}{0.0in}
\setlength{\evenoffset}{0.0in}

\endinput
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the paper first in portrait mode. It will then be switched internally:

```
\geometry{paperwidth=2in,paperheight=3.25in,margin=0pt}
```

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{cards.cfg}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1996/12/01]
\ProvidesFile{cards.cfg}
\newcommand{\cardpapermode}{landscape}
\newcommand{\cardpaper}{letterpaper}
\newcommand{\cardrows}{1}
\newcommand{\cardcolumns}{1}
\setlength{\cardheight}{2.0in}
\setlength{\cardwidth}{3.5in}
\setlength{\topoffset}{0.0in}
\setlength{\oddoffset}{0.0in}
\setlength{\evenoffset}{0.0in}

\endinput
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[cards,backs]{flashcards}
\geometry{paperwidth=2in,paperheight=3.25in,margin=0pt}
\begin{document}

    \begin{flashcard}{}
        Guten morgen.
    \end{flashcard}

    \begin{flashcard}{}
        Guten abend.
    \end{flashcard}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The orientation works for me with this change.  Do you know why there are extra blank pages?

Comment: If I set the card height to be slightly smaller (1.9in) in card.cfg, then the blank pages go away -- not sure why... there must be some kind of padding somewhere.

Comment: I suppose a trailing space in the code of flashcard. It is safe to use it like you did.